# Does anything obstruct Mostow-Prasad rigidity for orbifolds?

Tags: manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

If we phrase the Mostow-Prasad rigidity theorem algebraically,
it goes like this (let $\mathcal{H}^n$ be a model for hyperbolic $n$-space).

> For $n>2$: if $\Gamma,\Delta<\mathrm{Isom}(\mathfrak{h}^n)$ are discrete, isomorphic as groups, and $\mathrm{vol}(\mathcal{H}^n/\Gamma),\mathrm{vol}(\mathcal{H}^n/\Delta)<\infty$, then $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ are conjugate.

The topological interpretation generally given of this in the literature (Ratcliffe, Benedetti-Petronio, Bonahon) is that in dimension greater than $2$, if two finite-volume hyperbolic manifolds are homeomorphic, then they are isometric.

Is there anything stopping us from replacing the word "manifolds" with the word "orbifolds" there? The algebraic statements seems to translate the same way regardless of torsion.

Comment: The statement you wrote is complete?

Comment: If hyperbolic orbifolds are taken to be defined as quotients of $H^n$ etc by definition, then sure. It's not clear to me that the correct notion of "hyperbolic orbifold" isn't more general.

Comment: The theorem in the yellow box does not assume that $\Gamma,\Delta$ are torsion free, so the topological interpretation really is about hyperbolic orbifolds. When one reads about the hyperbolic manifold interpretation, then the theorem being interpreted has, properly speaking, a more restrictive hypothesis, requiring that $\Gamma,\Delta$ be torsion free.

Comment: @LeeMosher Right, and this is basically what I'm saying. Yet in the literature I know of, torsion is generally not mentioned in the algebraic phrasing, and orbifolds are generally not mentioned in the topological phrasing. Perhaps I am the only one bothered by this.

Comment: Part of the reason for that is that the topological setting has an alternative  formulation which does not apply to orbifold setting: assuming $\Gamma,\Delta$ are torsion free, if the quotient manifolds $\mathbb{H}^n/\Gamma$, $\mathbb{H}^n/\Delta$ are homotopy equivalent, then they are isometric. Trying to state this version in the orbifold setting is a bit of a nightmare, requiring one to develop an infrastructure of orbifold maps, orbifold homotopies, orbifold homotopy equivalences; not that it cannot be done, but in a book such as Ratcliffe or Bonahon it adds too much overhead.

Comment: But in the original sources, you'll find the theorems stated in their full generality.